# How can i make my social network app more efficient in storing and retriving the Data?

Tags: mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am working on a social network app from scratch,
I designed my database (choosing Mysql) to store and retrieve  data

The problem starts when I am posting videos and photos and when data become larger and larger when I am waiting to view news feeds (depending on sql query that brings the last posts from friends ans Pages).

The question is :
How can I manage and handle the big data, and how can I make the news feeds service more efficient ?

What do you think of using [(Real-time) Databases from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking about putting up Firebase as your choice for your database, then there's nothing wrong with that. Firebase realtime database is a very secure and great option.

Firebase gives you functionality like analytics, databases, messaging and crash reporting so you can move quickly and focus on your users.

Firebase is built on Google infrastructure and scales automatically, for even the largest apps.

And on top of that, many great apps do use Firebase as their backend.

I'd say to know more, you can just start with a demo project on Firebase to learn how the things happen with Firebase, and after learning, start using it as backend for your social app.

Just go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and start with your own project. To learn how to use Firebase, do refer [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) and if stuck, StackOverflow is always there.

If you want to get some inner details, I have some repositories on GitHub, that might help you in understanding about Firebase and the security rules and other important things.

[Demo App](https://github.com/Pradyuman7/ChattingDemoApp)

[Firebase Security Rules](https://github.com/Pradyuman7/CommonFirebaseJSON)

Comment: thanks for your great answer, actually there are many parameter we must consider to scale the social network, like the feed and how i am gonna manage the Feeds which are the new posts of the users, the most important thing is , How fast can i feed the users ?
and how often i should call the feed function and Update the users last feeds ?
i think this relate to the query (how much it's clean).
in Relational (DBMS) we can do tuning to increase the performance, 
what is the critical limit of Firebase ?
and how can i control it without losing high performance ?

Comment: @QusaiAzzam glad that you found my answer worthwhile. Well, Firebase is very fast, probably the fastest database option there is, provided you use the searching in a structured way. Firebase is based on nosql and hence there is not everything like in RDBMS and sql, but that never lets Firebase lag behind. Because you can structure your nodes and child nodes always in such a way that can suit you to bring the data in the most optimised way possible. So rest assured, Firebase would not be giving you up in terms of speed. But it would be good to dig in a bit more on their official website.

Comment: Also depending on your structure and your way, you can always do something that can optimise your performance, in almost every case. For example, you can create a node named feed, in which you can put sub nodes with imageURLs which are in order of your situation. Also I'd say do search out more to find how to do things with Firebase even more nicely :)

Comment: i really appreciate that, actually i have made research but you know the knowledge that (don't know it until you try it),  i have got advises to go with (Node.js + MongoDB) or ([rethinkdB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/)) but after doing research, i prefer to go with Firebase (Due to many things) such as : 
Sdks: they are supporting many platforms 
Availability, scale-ability,  High performance, supporting Instant Messaging, Cloud Storage .. that's make it a preferred choice over all ,
there are also other Nosql Databases such as HBase, Cassandra and really worth to read about them.

Comment: Absolutely @QusaiAzzam. If you found my answer useful, consider marking it as correct, this helps future stack overflow readers too and I'd appreciate that, Cheers! :)